# Calling javascript Method from Code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, function

This code worked in another page
But it's not working in the new page

#### JS Function to be called:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="Server">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function myfun() {
      alert("test");
    }
  </script>
</asp:Content>
```

#### Html code:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton CssClass="Link" ID="IMGDetail" 
         ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" 
         ImageUrl="~/Img/Detail.png" Height="19px" 
         Width="19px" OnClick="IMGDetail_Click" ToolTip="Detail" />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

#### Code behind:

```
protected void IMGDetail_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e) {
  LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton) sender;
  GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow) lbtn.NamingContainer;
  Label LabelTicketId = (gvr.FindControl("LBTicketId") as Label);
  Session["TicketId"] = LabelTicketId.Text;
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "myfun()", true);
}
```

Comment: Instead of `RegisterStartupScript` use `RegisterClientScriptBlock` or  if you look forward using `RegisterStartupScript` then define `function myfun() { ... }` before end of <body> tag not in <head> tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add following tag in your aspx page.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" />
```

In Codebehind

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(string), "myfun", "myfun()", true);
```